# How can I create a comparison between commits of a Pull Request when there is a merge commit among those commits?

Tags: github, github-api

My issue is related to GitHub API.

How can I create a comparison between commits of a Pull Request when there is a merge commit among those commits?

E.g.
In a new PR from feature branch to base branch. Consider the following flow:
- Developer creates a PR with one commit 111
- Developer pushes a new commit 222
- Developer realized that the base branch has new commits and merge it with feature branch
- Developer pushes another commit 333

How can I use GitHub API V3 or V4 to get a comparison between commits 111 and 333 without considering the merge commit? So, I can discover what are the changed/added lines only for a commit range (222 and 333) in a PR (like newest changes).

I know that the PR UI at GitHub already does this, and only show the changes from a commit range. However, there is no possibility to do it over API.

Regards